# MyBatis @Mapper declaration

Tags: java, spring-boot, orm, mybatis

Spring Boot | MyBatis

When I try to declare a mybatis mapper in controller, it gets underlined by IDE, and doesn't compile.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("demo")
@MapperScan("com.sample.mapper")
public class MessageController {

private static final String MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String INDEX = "index";

@Autowired
private MessageMapper messageMapper;


@RequestMapping("printMessage/{message}")
public String printMessage(ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute(MESSAGE, "M");
    return INDEX;
}

@RequestMapping("printHello")
public String printHello(ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute(MESSAGE, "Hello, ");
    return INDEX;
}
```

I got this class compiled somehow recently, however, when I try to use messageMapper instance, like `messageMapper.insert()` as it's not assigned any value, it gives me NullPointerException. It seems like Spring is for some reason is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documencation](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/apidocs/reference/org/mybatis/spring/annotation/MapperScan.html), I think the `@MapperScan` is not the right class, they cannot be autowired because they are not in the context on controller creation time. When it is defined in Mybatis XML config file, it is loaded with an Sql Session Factory Provider, a place that actually makes more sense, then it shall not be different with annotations style.